# Making visual installation script with progress bar

Tags: bash, shell, dialog, installation, progress-bar

**Introduction**: I am not among the best of programmers, so I apologize if this is an amateur question. But I am trying to make a `install.sh` shell script which can automate a linux installation. More specifically, I install Ubuntu Minimal/Netboot and then use my script to make the setup I want. But I would very much want to make the procedure prettier by having a progress bar and fill out the screen with a color (just like the first image) and I would also want for it to allow for the user to choose among a number of installation options using the arrow keys (like in the second image). If that is too difficult to do, a numbering option would also be fine. Is this very difficult to do?

**TL;DR**: I would like to make an installation script similar to the two images below.

[image: Ubuntu installation screen]
[image: Choose installation type]

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [dialog](http://hightek.org/projects/dialog/). It is based on ncurses, so it can be used without X.